# Building a specific list of str

Tags: python, string, list, tree

Here is the main class:

```
class GameStateNode:
    '''
    A tree of possible states for a two-player, sequential move, zero-sum,
    perfect-information game.

    value: GameState -- the game state at the root of this tree
    children: list -- all possible game states that can be reached from this
    game state via one legal move in the game.  children is None until grow
    is called.
    '''

    def __init__(self, game_state):
        ''' (GameStateNode, GameState) -> NoneType

        Initialize a new game state tree consisting of a single root node 
        that contains game_state.
        '''
        self.value = game_state
        self.children = []
```

Here are the functions I am currently working on:

```
def game_descriptions(root):
    ''' (GameStateNode) -> list of str

    Return a list containing a str describing each complete game that is
    possible from the game stored at root.

    Assume root is the root of a game state tree specifically for the game
    Subtract Square.

    >>> s = SubtractSquareState('p1', current_total = 6)
    >>> root = GameStateNode(s)
    >>> root.grow()
    >>> game_descriptions(root)
    ['p1:6 -> p2:2 -> p1:1 -> p2:0 = p1 wins!', 'p1:6 -> p2:5 -> p1:1 -> p2:0 = p1 wins!', 'p1:6 -> p2:5 -> p1:4 -> p2:0 = p1 wins!', 'p1:6 -> p2:5 -> p1:4 -> p2:3 -> p1:2 -> p2:1 -> p1:0 = p2 wins!']
    '''


def _build_paths(root, L = []):
    ''' (GameStateNode) -> list of str '''
    if root.children:
        for child in root.children:
            a = abbreviated(root.value)
            a += ' -> {}'.format(abbreviated(child.value))
            L.append(a)
            _build_paths(child, L)  
    else:
        pass
    return L

def abbreviated(s):
    '''(GameState) -> str

    Return an abbreviated str representation of SubtractSquareState s.
    '''

    return "{}:{}".format(s.next_player, s.current_total)
```

As you can see in fcn game_descriptions I need to return a list of game states in order with the winner at the end. My current problem is with fcn _build_paths. I want it to return a list of game descriptions without the winner, as I will implement who won in fcn game_descriptions.
I want this, for example:

```
>>> root = GameStateNode(SubtractSquareState('p1', current_total = 4))
>>> root.grow()
>>> _build_paths(root)
['p1:4 -> p2:0', 'p1:4 -> p2:3 -> p1:2 -> p2:1 -> p1:0']
```

Instead I get this:

```
['p1:4 -> p2:0', 'p1:4 -> p2:3', 'p2:3 -> p1:2', 'p1:2 -> p2:1', 'p2:1 -> p1:0']
```

Comment: What's `SubtractSquareState('p1', current_total = 4))`?

Comment: A SubtractSquareState is a current state of the game SubtractSquare, where players subtract the square of a number from the current total in an attempt to reach 0 (i.e. 1, 4, 9, 16). In this case, at current_total = 4, you can subtract either 4 or 1, resulting in a next state being either 'p2:0' or 'p2:3'. And so on.

Comment: I have less than 4 hours to hand in this assignment so any help/ideas are welcome!

Comment: What does root.grow() do?

Comment: It would be easier if you post the code to all these answers? Its kind of hard at east for me to follow with the missing parts

Answer (score 0):

Because you want a list of strings, you need to build up a string indicating the current path separately from the list of all strings. You can also use this to indicate the starting point so you can avoid  listing each node twice in each path.

Without all of your code, I can't test this, but I think something of this general form would work:

```
def _build_paths(root, currentpath, L = []):
    ''' (GameStateNode) -> list of str '''
    if root.children:
        for child in root.children:
            a = ' -> {}'.format(abbreviated(child.value))
            currentpath += a
            _build_paths(child, currentpath, L)  
    else:
        L.append(currentpath)
    return L
```

You would call this with:

```
_build_paths(root, abbreviated(root.value))
```